# Insert value in Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to insert data to a database using button click as:

In my **MainActivity**, I am using:

```
 package com.example.trial;

 public CityViewModel  mcityViewModel;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ImageButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String cityName = cityNameWeakReference.getText().toString();
        City cityItem = new City(cityName, 5.0,4.0);
        Snackbar.make(view, cityName+cityItem, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
        mcityViewModel.insert(cityItem);
      }
    });
```

For easier look at the database related code, I have defined all database related files in `com.example.trial.db` (except the `DbActivity` which shows the `recyclerview`).

My **Entity**

```
package com.example.trial.db

Entity(tableName = "city_table")
public class City {

  @NonNull
  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
  private String city = "Atlantis";

  @NonNull
  @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")
  private Double latitude = 0.0;

  @NonNull
  @ColumnInfo(name = "Longitude")
  private Double longitude = 0.0;

  public City(@NonNull String city, @NonNull Double latitude, @NonNull Double longitude) {
    this.city = city;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
  }

  ... getter and setter for city, latitude and longitude ...
  ... not showing for brevity. If you think that is necessary, please ask...
```

the **Dao**

```
package com.example.trial.db

@Dao
public interface CityDao{

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
  void insert(City city);

  @Query("DELETE FROM city_table")
  void deleteAll();

  @Delete
  void deleteCity(City city);

  @Query("SELECT * from city_table LIMIT 1")
  City[] getAnyCity();

  @Query("SELECT * from city_table ORDER BY city ASC")
  LiveData<List<City>> getAllCity();
}
```

and the **ViewModel** is

```
package com.example.trial.db

public class CityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private CityRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<City>> mAllCity;

    public CityViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new CityRepository(application);
        mAllCity = mRepository.getAllCity();
    }

    public LiveData<List<City>> getAllCity() {
        return mAllCity;
    }

    public void insert(City city) { mRepository.insert(city); }
    public void deleteCity(City city) { mRepository.deleteCity(city); }
    public void deleteAll() {
        mRepository.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

Now, when I run the code, I am getting an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.trial.db.CityViewModel.insert(com.example.trial.db.City)' on a null object reference
```

The `snackbar` is giving some value, which shows, `cityItem` is not null either, but still I am getting this error.

I am very new to java and trying to build this from [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-room-delete-data/#6) `codelabs`. But I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not initialising `mcityViewModel` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Please add this line in `onCreate` method:

`mcityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CityViewModel.class);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // -------> Add this line here <-------
    mcityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CityViewModel.class);

    ImageButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String cityName = cityNameWeakReference.getText().toString();
        City cityItem = new City(cityName, 5.0,4.0);
        Snackbar.make(view, cityName+cityItem, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
        mcityViewModel.insert(cityItem);
      }
    });
}
```