# OnSuccessListner for Room database Insert

Tags: android

This is my insert to a database (the Entity, Dao and the viewModel is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464808/insert-value-in-room-database))

```
    ImageButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String cityName = cityNameWeakReference.getText().toString();
        City cityItem = new City(cityName, Lat, Long);
//        Snackbar.make(view, cityName + Lat+Long, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//            .setAction("Action", null).show();
        mcityViewModel.insert(cityItem);
      }
    });
```

I want a snackbar/toast onsuccess of the insert. Kindly help me doing that.

Answer (score 0):

define your insert method the following way:

```
Long insert(City cityItem);
```

When you invoke it, it should return the new column id, if the new column id is not 0, then the insert was successful

```
long result = mcityViewModel.insert(cityItem);
if(result!=0) {
   //success
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details in your answer? How does this trigger a notification?

Comment: it doesn't trigger the notification, the OP wanted to know "when" to trigger it, not how to trigger it